# Nested Loop Counter

Tags: c#, winforms, radgridview

I am trying to create a nested loop, that takes a given number 'Views Per Sheet' and depending on this number, lets start with (1) will count 00,01,02,03,04,05,06...
Now if the number is (2) will count 00,00,01,01,02,02
number is now (3) will count 00,00,00,01,01,01

I have tried many variations of the below code and what I have pasted is not the closest I have gotten my my desired result but I am brain mushed and can't seem to figure out what seems to be a simple operation.  I can't word my google search well enough to find a comparison.

Please see attached images to see what I wish to do.

Edit...
The form is a radGridView by Telerik

```cs
public void ViewsPerSheetChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int numViewsPerSheet = (int)thisForm.numViewsPerSheet.Value;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numViewsPerSheet; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Models.Count; j++)
        {
            Models[j].SheetObjModel.SheetNumber = i.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
            if (j == numViewsPerSheet - 1)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    thisForm.RefreshDataGrid();
}
```

[image: Image One]

[image: Image Two]

[image: Image Three]

Comment: You need only one loop and a sheetIndex. Increment sheetIndex only if i%NumViewsPerSheet == 0.

Comment: What if the number of items cannot be divided by the number of sheets?

Comment: What @Fildor said will work - just use the modulo operator..

Comment: Olivier, how was my question not clear, or missing a goal or difficulty? What have I done so far?  The down arrow say, 'doesn't show enough research', How is research measured?  This seem like a boiler plate response.  My question managed to return two very good replies by two individuals who understood what I was asking.  So I am very confused by your comment.  I will heed your comment for my next question on this site.  Thanks

Comment: The control is radGridView

Comment: @Olivier, I have edited and added a tag to the telerik radgridview as requested.  a generic cc...  I knew it...  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it. You don't really need a nested loop here. Use integer division for the sheet number. I repeat the same number `x` number of times where `x` is the number of views per sheet.

Try:

```
    public void ViewsPerSheetChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int numViewsPerSheet = (int)thisForm.numViewsPerSheet.Value;

        for (int j = 0; j < Models.Count; j++)
        {
            int i = j/numViewsPerSheet; // 0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2... for num=3
            Models[j].SheetObjModel.SheetNumber = i.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');          
        }
        thisForm.RefreshDataGrid();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Example using the modulo operator:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int numViewsPerSheet = 2;
        int sheetIndex = 0;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 7; i++ )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sheet: {0:00}", sheetIndex);
            if( (i+1)%numViewsPerSheet==0)sheetIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

See https://dotnetfiddle.net/xnCMts

Result:

```
Sheet: 00
Sheet: 00
Sheet: 01
Sheet: 01
Sheet: 02
Sheet: 02
Sheet: 03
```

Adapted to your code:

```
public void ViewsPerSheetChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int viewIndex = 0;
    int numViewsPerSheet = Math.Max((int)thisForm.numViewsPerSheet.Value, 1); // never trust user input!

    for (int i = 0; i < Models.Count; i++) {
        Models[i].SheetObjModel.SheetNumber = viewIndex.ToString("00");
        if ( (i+1)%numViewsPerSheet==0) viewIndex++;
    }
    thisForm.RefreshDataGrid();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replies, your examples are very helpful, I managed to make it work with a while loop.

```
public void ViewsPerSheetChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int numViewsPerSheet = (int)thisForm.numViewsPerSheet.Value;

        int cnt = 0;
        int num = 0;
        if (numViewsPerSheet < 1)
        {
            return;
        }
        while (cnt < Models.Count)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numViewsPerSheet; i++)
            {
                Models[cnt].SheetObjModel.SheetNumber = num.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
                cnt++;
                if (cnt == Models.Count) break;
                
            }
            num++;
        }
    thisForm.RefreshDataGrid();
    }
```